# EditorTemplate + Model not being returned on POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I can't seem to figure this out, it is driving me crazy!

Essentially, I have a list of rows I need to display with one drop down list per row.

I have a view model:

```
public class UserMembershipViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    public List<ProgramMembership> ProgramMembership { get; set; }
}
```

In my parent view I have, as you can see I am using an editor template which is located in "/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ProgramMembership.cshtml":

```
@using AcnCS.Model
@model AcnCS.Model.ViewModels.User.UserMembershipViewModel 
@{
    ViewBag.PageHeader = "Membership for " + Model.User.FullName;
    ViewBag.PageTitle = "Membership for " + @Model.User.FullName;
    ViewBag.HideNav = true;
}

    @if (Model.ProgramMembership != null)
    {
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div id="permissions">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Program</td>
                                    <td>Effective Membership?</td>
                                    <td>Permission Type</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                             @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.ProgramMembership, "ProgramMembership")

                        </table>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes"/>
                    }

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

My Editor template (ProgramMembership.cshtml) is:

```
@using AcnCS.Model
@model List<AcnCS.Model.ProgramMembership>

@foreach(ProgramMembership membership in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@membership.ProgramName</td>
        <td>
            @if (membership.IsMember)
            {
                <span class="label label-success">@membership.IsMember</span>
            }
            else
            {
                @membership.IsMember
            }
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => membership.PermissionType, membership.PermissionTypes)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Everything is being displayed properly, but when I submit, my model object is null, even the ProgramMembership property in the model is null:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Membership(UserMembershipViewModel model)
    {

        // model IS NULL!!

        return View(model);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pluralize the Property name since it is a collection, for better readability

```
public class UserMembershipViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    public List<ProgramMembership> ProgramMemberships { get; set; }
}
```

and you dont need a Loop inside your EditorTemplate file

```
@model AcnCS.Model.ProgramMembership
<tr>
    <td>@membership.ProgramName</td>
    <td>
      @if (membership.IsMember)
      {
         <span class="label label-success">@membership.IsMember</span>
      }
      else
      {
         @membership.IsMember
      }
    </td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => membership.PermissionType, membership.PermissionTypes)</td>
</tr>
```

In your main view,call your EditorTemplate like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.ProgramMemberships)
```