# EditorTemplates Issue - Returning only the first element from a list on Post event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, datatables

I'm trying to do a filtering page for a report using Asp.Net MVC4 with Razor. To achieve this, I developed a ViewModel-like class containing three secondary viewmodel object lists (which I will present them on small grids inside the page)

```
public class DeviationReportViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public int Type { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Companies")]
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Departments")]
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Employees")]
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Event")]
    public Event ChosenEvent { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
}
```

The Company, Department and Employee classes basically contains Id(int), Name and Description (both strings), A string property for the Foreign Key description (Department which an Employee belongs to, for an example), and a Selected(boolean) properties. For each one I developed an EditorTemplate like this one:

```
// ~\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Employee.cshtml
@model Model.ViewModels.Employee

<tr id="@Model.Id">
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Selected, new { @class = "selectEmp" }) 
        // I use this for filtering values between tables, using javascript 
        // (i.e.: to show only Employees from a Department)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Department)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Department, new { @class = "fk" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I retrieve those lists from DB, they contain several objects (i.e.: Employee list have 10 objects), but when I post back the viewmodel with the selections, the Employee list contains only one object. This don't occur with Company and Department lists. Since I don't remove anything from the lists (I just use the "Selected" property to properly filtering them), where I am getting wrong?

(I've googled through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158001/posting-a-list-of-view-models-in-a-model-in-asp-net-mvc-4), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158001/posting-a-list-of-view-models-in-a-model-in-asp-net-mvc-4), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458176/editortemplate-model-not-being-returned-on-post) articles, but I still not get it)

**EDIT - JS Scripts used for filtering (with jQuery DataTables)**

```
function GetColumn(class) {
    if (class == '.selectCom') {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }
};

//this function returns a keyword list for filtering
function GetSearchArray(tbl, searchClass) {
    if (searchClass === null || searchClass === undefined) {
        searchClass = '';
        return new Array();
    }
    else {
        var searchArray = new Array();
        $(searchClass).toArray().forEach(function (item, index, array) {
            if ($(item).is(':checked')) {
                tbl.settings.currentColumn = GetColumn(searchClass);
                searchArray.push($(item).parents('tr')[0].cells[1].innerHTML);
            }
        });
        return searchArray;
    }
};

// this function effectively filters a child table based on what is selected on parent table
function TableFilter(parentTableId, parentClassName, childTableId, childClassName) {
    var tbl = $(childTableId).dataTable();
    var keywords = GetSearchArray($(parentTableId).DataTable(), parentClassName);
    var filter = '';
    keywords.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        filter = (filter !== '') ? filter + '|' + item : item;
    });
    tbl.fnFilter(filter, GetColumn(childClassName), true, false, false, true);
};

// These events call the filtering function and clear what is selected on child tables.
$('.selectCom').change(function () {
    TableFilter('#tbCom', '.selectCom', '#tbDep', '.selectDep');
    $('.selectDep').prop('checked', false);
    $('.selectEmp').prop('checked', false);
});

$('.selectDep').change(function () {
    TableFilter('#tbDep', '.selectDep', '#tbEmp', '.selectEmp');
    $('.selectEmp').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: You code here looks fine so there must be some other issue. What is the script doing? Are you disabling any elements?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've added script details. Thank you for the interest.

Comment: Difficult to tell because I'm not familiar with `jQuery DataTables` but the key to posting back a collection is that the indexers must start a zero and be consecutive. If your filtering out items (e.g. you have `<input name="Employees[0].Name ..> <input name="Employees[2].Name ..>` it will not post back correctly if <input name="Employees[1].Name ..> is missing). If that's the issue then you will need a `for` loop and add a hidden input with an index property which allows you to post back not consecutive indexed items (`<input type="hidden" name="Employees[@i].Index" value = "@i" />`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke your comment gave me the clue. Check out the answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. FYI, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314077/passing-collection-as-model-without-ordered-index/26314136#26314136) explains what I was talking about in my last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the problem was on client-side, since "fnFilter" function from DataTables.Net **removes objects effectively**  from those lists inside my viewmodel. This way, I think that the "fnFilter" mess around with EditorTemplate's indexes (and scramble them), and on POST, ASP.NET MVC doesn't know how to reconstruct those indexes.

So what should we do? I've changed my filtering function on client-side just to hide filtered rows (adding a "display:none" class for each filtered row). So, when we post back the form, the list remains intact, including selected values. The indexes were perfect.

Thanks to @StephenMuecke who gave me the clue.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to do something like this [Example of Posting Collections to Controller](http://blog.mitjagti.com/post/2012/08/06/Posting-ArrayList-of-objects-or-a-single-object-in-MVC.aspx).

Your editor template will have to be a foreach() loop, and the iterate through the loop and manually set the name and id of each element. So , something like the below.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Employees.Count ; i++){
    <input type="textbox" name="Employees[i].Name" id="Employees[i].Name" />
    ...
    ...
    // if Employees is a list and contains a list as a property then
    for(int x =0; x < Employees[i].Departments.Count; x++){
        <input type="textbox" name="Employees[i].Departments[x]" ...
```

I know departments isn't a list, but that is an example of how you do it.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but as stated on the third link that I've mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11458302/1475630), we don't need to iterate over collections, since Editor Templates effectively do that for us...