# Passing collection as model without ordered index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have list of objects and I'm passing it to view and it is rendered properly.
[image]

When I submit this form, I'm getting getting the same model. Everything works fine.
Unfortunately, when I decide to delete dynamically some record using jquery, so it looks like this
[image]
After submitting form, I'm getting only list with 2 first items. It's probably, because indexes arent in a natural order (0,1,3 instead of 0,1,2).
Is there anything I could do to fix it easily (not using jquery to change inputs, smth server sided)? I've tried to change array to List or Ienumerable but still nothing. I know I could pack everything up and send as json or just read the formCollection, but I'd like to ask here first and see if there is some other solution.

Comment: Are you using a `for` loop or a custom `EditorTemplate` to render the collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to include an input for the `Index` property which allows you to post back non consecutive indexers. The value of the index must match the collection indexer. For example

```
for(int i = 0; i < model.tagList.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.tagList[i].Name);
  <input type="hidden" name="tagList.Index" value="@i" />
}
```

Comment: I'm worried it doesn't work. I've added Index property, added html hidden helper to razor view, it outputs very same html you wrote. Still, very same behaviour. Also, I don't understand why would this in ur opinion work? I mean, isn't that just an additional property?

Comment: Yes, but the `DefaultModelBinder` fails for non-consecutive indexers **unless** there is an `Index` property. So you could have `<input name="tagList[abc].Name" value="Tag1"> <input name="tagList[abc].Index" value="abc" />` and `<input name="tagList[xyz].Name" value="Tag2"> <input name="tagList[xyz].Index" value="xyz" />` and it will post back a collection of 2 items

Comment: You said you _"added Index property"_. If you meant to your model, then dont (`Index` is a property of `IList`)

Comment: The name of the _hidden_ inputs should be `tagList.Index`, not `tagList[@i].Index`. Besides that everything is correct. See **Non-Sequential Indices** part of the [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) for more details.

Comment: Oops, Thanks @Zabavsky, well spotted.