# validation Message when I use <script type="text/template"> with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using this Code to make a row template to be added to my table from Jquery 
I can add it without any problem else the validation Message does'nt displayed

```
    <script type="text/template" id="template">
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "Q form-control"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Quantity)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => item.SingleCost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "S form-control"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.SingleCost)
        </td>
</script>
```

in my  Java script i use this

```
function Addrow(){
    var newClass = "newrow"+x;
    var tablerow = '<tr class="Calculated ' + newClass + '">';
    tablerow += $('#template').html();
    tablerow += '</tr>';

    $('#tb').append(tablerow);}
```

I got  output like this

```
    <input class="S form-control text-box single-line valid" data-val="true"
    data-val-number="The field single_cost must be a number." data-val-required="thisFieldIsReq"      id="item_SingleCost" name="item.SingleCost"  value="0.00" type="text">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="item.SingleCost" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

the validation message doesn't displayed when I submit my form

***Note:*** *when i use this code without template and directly without Javascript Fuction all thing is OK and validation Message appear*

thank you :)

Comment: If your wanting client side validation for dynamically added elements then you need to re-parse the form. [Refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542509/validate-dynamically-added-fields/26542591#26542591)

Comment: As a side note, you are adding controls with duplicate name attributes so this wont bind to a collection on post back (if that what your intending to do). And its also creating duplicate ID's which is invalid html.

Comment: mmmmm now how ican solve this

Comment: If you want to create a collection of objects, then they need to be named correctly e.g. `<input name="[0].Quantity ..>`, `<input name="[1].Quantity ..>` etc. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026374/adding-another-pet-to-a-model-form/24027152#24027152) will help you get started (read the comments also) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314077/passing-collection-as-model-without-ordered-index/26314136#26314136)

Comment: thank you @StephenMuecke 
i use str.replace() to replace word item in  my string tablerow 
like this and it's work now

    tablerow = tablerow.replace(/\item\b/gi, "item" + x);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after @stephenMuecke Commit

when i add it like below all thing is good

the solution by add

```
$('form').data('validator', null);
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
```